# Convert this date string to NSDate "2016-09-23T23:06:00+00:00"

Tags: ios, string, swift, date, nsdate

I Was trying to convert this string to a NSDate,
it works for USA Location, but when i changed to Brazil. Bumm , It crashes!
Which is the format string that I should use?

This is my code:

```
static func textToDatedateString: String) -> NSDate {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+00:00"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!

    return date
}
```

Comment: Provide details about the crash.

Comment: it returns nil, and crash for "unnable to wrap nil value"

Comment: Set the date formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: MAN! YOU'RE AWESOME! THX

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the timezone info at your string. This way you are inputing the time as local time when it actually is UTC +00:00. Also you are forcing unwrapping your string, it would crash your app if you input an invalid string date. Try like this:

```
func textToDate(dateString: String) -> NSDate? {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}

if let dateFromString = textToDate("2016-09-23T23:06:00+00:00") {
    print(dateFromString)   // "2016-09-23 23:06:00 +0000"
}
```